# Format page numbers

Tags: formatting, header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

How can I control look of the page numbers? For example, in the *MWE* below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=3.81cm,right=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{11}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
    \begin{singlespace}
        John Doe \\
        March 2012 \\
        Department of Computer Science \\
    \end{singlespace}
\end{flushright}
\begin{center}
    Some Generic Title \\
\bigskip
    \textbf{\underline{Abstract}}
\end{center}
\vspace{-13pt}
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah.

Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah.

Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah.

\end{document}}
```

I would like to have the page number look like:

> -xi-

instead of:

> xi

Comment: You could also use `\usepackage[margin=1in,left=1.5in]{geometry}`, since `1in`=`2.54cm`.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Also, note that this is by no means an MWE (Minimal Working Example), have a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. For your problem, an MWE might look like: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=3.81cm,right=2.54cm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{11}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your example, replace (loaded *before* `geometry`)

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

with (loaded *after* `geometry`)

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{--~\thepage~--}
```

`\fancyfoot[C]{--~\thepage~--}` ("C" stands for "centered") will change the formatting of the page number in the footer as desired. (`\pagestyle{fancy}` is simply necessary to activate the features of the `fancyhdr` package; loading `fancyhdr` *after* `geometry` is needed to make `fancyhdr` recognize the margin changes effected by `geometry`.)

Note that redefining `\thepage` itself by, e.g., writing

```
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{--~\roman{page}~--}
```

is a *bad* idea because this will also affect the page number format in, e.g., cross-references.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=3.81cm,right=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{--~\thepage~--}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{11}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
    \begin{singlespace}
        John Doe \\
        March 2012 \\
        Department of Computer Science \\
    \end{singlespace}
\end{flushright}
\begin{center}
    Some Generic Title \\
\bigskip
    \textbf{\underline{Abstract}}
\end{center}
\vspace{-13pt}
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah.

Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah.

Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may need to remove the header rule using `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`.

Comment: Werner - you are the genius!