# LaTex: Page numbers between hyphens

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

How do I get page numbers to appear like:

```
- 1 -
```

I followed [Format page numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40114/format-page-numbers) but it just added an annoying header at the top of the page:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{--~\thepage~--}

\title{...}
...

\begin{document}
\maketitle
...
```

[image: incorrect page number style]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\maketitle` calls `\pagestyle{plain}`. This page style can be redefined, see [`fancyhdr`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf), "7 Redefining `plain` style":

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% clears all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{--~\thepage~--}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clears all header and footer fields
  \fancyfoot[C]{--~\thepage~--}%
  \renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\title{My title}  
\author{My author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```

Of course, code repetition can be avoided, e.g.:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% clears all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{--~\thepage~--}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother
```

or

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{--~\thepage~--}%
  \renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Or without any additional package:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\ps@plain{%
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil--~\thepage~--\hfil}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Unrelated but I am annoyed at LaTex that I need 11 lines of (repetitive) code with dependency on external library just to get hyphens around page numbers (not to mention the amount of documentation I need to read and default behaviors I need to know).

Comment: @takfuruya This could be done in a simpler, one-line way by using `\renewcommand{\thepage}{---~\arabic{page}~---}`.
However, this approach will alter/change `\thepage` *everywhere* the page number is displayed, including references.  Thus, Heiko's method is the necessary way to go.