# Page number format

Tags: formatting, page-numbering

How can i get page numbers like that R1, R2 for reference pages?

Here is a Word-based example of what I try to achieve:

[image: word]

Comment: A quick search will find you many possible answers, such as this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40114/format-page-numbers

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\thepage{R\arabic{page}}

hello

\end{document}
```

Depending upon what packages you are using there may be better alternatives.

Comment: You may also want to provide the instruction `\pagenumbering{arabic}` immediately before `\renewcommand\thepage{R\arabic{page}}` in case the page numbers need to restart from 1.

Comment: @Mico I'd use `\setcounter{page}{1}` as this just resets the page counter whereas `\pagenumbering` plays with the formatting as well...

Comment: Should the page number be reset to `0` instead of `1`?

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, no. The page number is presumably incremented at shipout so as long as you are already on the new page `\setconter{page}{1}` is correct.